# Login Django-project

Tags: python, django, django-models

[image]

Hello, help me figure out the logic behind the Django ezine. Each student should have many grades in different disciplines. Is there a "tuple" field type in django?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Postgres as a backend you ca use JSONField: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield

Or you can use a ManyToMany relationship to model it in a more classic RDBMS system: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

The way you want to go really depends on the query patterns and how your entities are supposed to interact with each other.

Comment: It is necessary that when you click on a group, the disciplines that belong to this group are displayed, when you click on a discipline, students who study it with grades are displayed, something like this (below the screen) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jSIkLAJorHsO_-cvYE1FeIxwg_qldttK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I think you can experiment with both methods. The JSONField can be tricky if there are a lot of disciplines. Alternatively, you can define a new model called "Grade" which has a foreign key to the Student model, a foreign key to the Discipline model and an int field representing the grade. I would probably go for a solution like this in a production ready app. It scales better and, for example, you can easily extend the Grade model to include comments on the grade etc.

Answer (score 0):

Having tuples as a value for a field violates the first normal form
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

If each student has many grades (one-to-many), you can create a separate table and the table should have a student column (as foreign key) which points to the student with these grades.

If the relation is many-to-many, you can use many-to-many as suggested by the other answer.

For simplicity of queries (but some complications on parsing), you can use Jsonfield if you are using Postgresql.

Behavior of what happen when you click a certain thing are completely at your control, so you can write multiple queries.